# Grails 3.0.4 deploying localhost but not remotely

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, ubuntu-14.04

Someone help please...I am able to run:

```
grails run-app
```

and access my application on localhost:8080. However, I have no luck deploying to Tomcat 7.052 on Ubuntu 14.04.1LTS. The war file uploads successfully using the Tomcat Web Manager but I get HTTP error 404 upon accessing via the browser. I am clicking on the application link on the Tomcat Web Manager to access the applications. I tried deploying the sample.war file from Tomcat examples and it works.

Here is what I have tried:

1) I changed my build.gradle file from:

```
...
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
...
```

to:

```
...
provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
...
```

2) I ran:

```
grails war
```

to generate a war file in which I then uploaded successfully using Tomcat Web Manager.

3) I also tried restarting the tomcat service.

Here is my grails-app/conf/application.yml file:

```
---
grails:
    profile: web
    codegen:
        defaultPackage: myApp
info:
    app:
        name: '@info.app.name@'
        version: '@info.app.version@'
        grailsVersion: '@info.app.grailsVersion@'
spring:
    groovy:
        template:
            check-template-location: false

---
grails:
    mime:
        disable:
            accept:
                header:
                    userAgents:
                        - Gecko
                        - WebKit
                        - Presto
                        - Trident
        types:
            all: '*/*'
            atom: application/atom+xml
            css: text/css
            csv: text/csv
            form: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            html: 
              - text/html
              - application/xhtml+xml
            js: text/javascript
            json:
              - application/json
              - text/json
            multipartForm: multipart/form-data
            pdf: application/pdf
            rss: application/rss+xml
            text: text/plain
            hal: 
              - application/hal+json
              - application/hal+xml
            xml:
              - text/xml
              - application/xml
    urlmapping:
        cache:
            maxsize: 1000
    controllers:
        defaultScope: singleton
    converters:
        encoding: UTF-8
    views:
        default:
            codec: html
        gsp:
            encoding: UTF-8
            htmlcodec: xml
            codecs:
                expression: html
                scriptlets: html
                taglib: none
                staticparts: none
---
hibernate:
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: true
        use_query_cache: false
        region.factory_class: 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' 

dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password:

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create-drop
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 #  TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

Comment: What's in the tomcat log? It should contain a splendid stack trace :)

Answer (score 0):

After digging into the log files (catalina.out) embedded below, I found out that Tomcat was using Java 7 whilst my grails application had used Java 8. Here is what I did:

1) I installed Java 8 on my server and set Tomcat to use it. This has significantly slowed down my Tomcat though.

2) I then configured my dataSource in grails-app/conf/application.yml to include the correct configurations for MySQL database. These configuration are in Grails 3.x documentation under dataSource.

3) Lastly, I included

```
runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
```

in my gradle.build dependencies.

```
Sep 09, 2015 2:47:32 AM org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection loadClass
FINE: Failed to load class [{0}]
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: myApp/ApplicationLoader : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class myApp.ApplicationLoader)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2948)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1208)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.loadClass(Introspection.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2117)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2056)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2030)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2023)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:873)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```